# getting problem in .htaccess file 403 error

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, http-status-code-403

i have file .htaccess
here is the sources of .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$    /index.php/$2/?page=$1  

[L]
</IfModule>
```

and when i open localhost it error of 403 FORBIDDEN
You don't have permission to access /index.php on this server.

how i fix ?

Comment: First off all whats your intended output of the htaccess which you placed? Asking since this htaccess seems error. Using this htaccess if a user enters URL say "https://example.com/index.php" he will be redirected to "https://example.com/index.php//?page=index.php" (yes u see it wright, its two slashes after index.php) which will of course throw error only.

Comment: @RajaGopal "its two slashes after index.php) which will of course throw error only" - You wouldn't necessarily expect that to throw an error. Multiple slashes are reduced to single slashes anyway when the request is mapped to the filesystem and the additional slash after `index.php` is simply additional pathname information (PATH_INFO) that the handler for `.php` requests normally accepts.

Comment: Is that your actual `.htaccess` file? The last directive is split onto two lines - as posted, this would result in an error, if it's being processed at all. What version of Apache are you using? Have you enabled `.htaccess` overrides and mod_rewrite on you local dev server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when I remove this one line

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

the problem was solve